# Difference in 'step' for 2 Matrices of the same image in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

Why is the 'step' value for 2 matrices for the same image different?

One of them is generated by `LoadImageM()` and another by `GetMat()` after the image was loaded with `LoadImage()`. My code is:

```
import cv2.cv as cv
def main():
    org_win = 'Original'
    cv.NamedWindow(org_win, cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    org_img = cv.LoadImage("bed.jpg", cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
    cv.ShowImage(org_win, org_img)

    org_img_mat1 = cv.LoadImageM("bed.jpg", cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
    org_img_mat2 = cv.GetMat(org_img, 0)

    print org_img_mat1
    print org_img_mat2

    cv.WaitKey(0)
    cv.DestroyWindow(org_win)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
<cvmat(type=42424010 8UC3 rows=497 cols=681 step=2043 )>
<cvmat(type=42420010 8UC3 rows=497 cols=681 step=2044 )>
```

What is causing this difference in step value? Kindly enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the source code for `cv.LoadImage` and `cv.LoadImageM`:

```
static PyObject *pycvLoadImage(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kw)
{
  const char *keywords[] = { "filename", "iscolor", NULL };
  char *filename;
  int iscolor = CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kw, "s|i", (char**)keywords, &filename, &iscolor))
    return NULL;

  // Inside ALLOW_THREADS, must not reference 'filename' because it might move.
  // So make a local copy 'filename_copy'.
  char filename_copy[2048];
  strncpy(filename_copy, filename, sizeof(filename_copy));

  IplImage *r;
  Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
  r = cvLoadImage(filename_copy, iscolor);
  Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS

  if (r == NULL) {
    PyErr_SetFromErrnoWithFilename(PyExc_IOError, filename);
    return NULL;
  } else {
    return FROM_IplImagePTR(r);
  }
}

static PyObject *pycvLoadImageM(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kw)
{
  const char *keywords[] = { "filename", "iscolor", NULL };
  char *filename;
  int iscolor = CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kw, "s|i", (char**)keywords, &filename, &iscolor))
    return NULL;

  // Inside ALLOW_THREADS, must not reference 'filename' because it might move.
  // So make a local copy 'filename_copy'.
  char filename_copy[2048];
  strncpy(filename_copy, filename, sizeof(filename_copy));

  CvMat *r;
  Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
  r = cvLoadImageM(filename_copy, iscolor);
  Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS

  if (r == NULL) {
    PyErr_SetFromErrnoWithFilename(PyExc_IOError, filename);
    return NULL;
  } else {
    return FROM_CvMatPTR(r);
  }
}
```

It looks like the main difference is `return FROM_IplImagePTR(r)` vs. `return FROM_CvMatPTR(r)` maybe `step` is one-based indexing in `IplImage` but zero-based indexing in `CvMat`?

Comment: Or maybe not? For many other images the step value is the same in both cases. However, almost all of those images were standard sizes you get from cameras, like (1600, 1200), (640, 480) etc.

The not so usual (681, 497) size might be responsible for this behavior but I have no reason to believe so.

Comment: @AbhinavSood Interesting... Does it do this when you use `cvCreateImage` or `cvCreateMat`?

Comment: `org_img = cv.LoadImage("bed.jpg", cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)`

`org_img_mat1 = cv.LoadImageM("bed.jpg", cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)`

`org_img_mat2 = cv.GetMat(org_img, 0)`


`print org_img_mat1`

`print org_img_mat2`

@mevatron Not using either CreateImage or CreateMat.